# Can't clone Git Repository, even I added Public Key to GIthub

Tags: git, github, clone

I bought a new M1 Macbook Air, and I started to setup my on laptop. I installed Git, and I cloned my repository with

```
git clone git@github.com:xibotlab/homepage.git
```

Then there was an error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I knew that to solve this error I must add Git Public Key to Github, so I entered this:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "xibotmoon@gmail.com"
```

and I added Public Key to Github successfully.

But even I added Public Key, there was an error above. I searched on Github but I couldn't solve this problem, because all documents saids I must add Public Key, and I already did! How do I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Something else must be going on (maybe having to do with the M1-ness of the machine? Maybe git doesn't work unless you do something else.). You don't need "permission" to clone that repo: it's public! I said `git clone git@github.com:xibotlab/homepage.git` and bingo.

Answer (score 2):

Try first switching to HTTPS, especially for a public repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/xibotlab/homepage.git
```

Regarding SSH, test the SSH access first, before trying to clone:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

If you don't see a Welcome message, but the same Permission Denied error, you will have more debug information to investigate.

Comment: Could you point the direction of such investigations? No welcome message for me....

Comment: @SigmaOctantis {Source "Testing your SSH connection"](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection). The welcome message should be "`Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`". Check the output of ssh -Tv to see what public key is offered. Make sure said public key was registered to your GitHub account.